# Error while executing SOQL through rest api

Tags: soql, rest-api

When I am trying to execute SOQL using `OAuthRestTemplate` Rest API with following URL:

> https://na98.salesforce.com/services/data/v46.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+Name+from+Account+where+SAP_ID_UCID__c+=+'1000479'

I am getting below error:

> [{"message":"\nSELECT+Name+from+Account+where+SAP_ID_UCID__c+=+'1000479'\n     ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:6\nunexpected token: '+'","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]

And also tried encoding the URL and query param. but no luck

but when I execute the same URL in any rest client like post man, it is giving response.

I am doing any wrong in java ? Please help

Comment: What's in your actual code? It looks like you might be supplying the query pre-encoded and then having it be encoded a second time.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error and the same scenario: worked in workbench did not work in Java.  As suggested above, I removed the manual URL Encoding step.  Java seems to be automatically encoding.  Here's the final code that worked.

```
response = client.send(HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                        .uri(UriComponentsBuilder
                                .fromHttpUrl(token.getInstanceUrl())
                                .path(path)
                                .queryParam("q", query)
                                .build()
                                .toUri())
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "OAuth " + token.getToken())
                        .GET()
                        .build(),
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

I got it to work by removing the step that was manually encoding the query before building the HTTPRequest.